# ¿Porque no puedo ver los iconos de Glyphicon en mi pagina hecha con bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap, web, icons

Baje una plantilla y solo le añadí algunas funciones de php, pero cuando entro a mi pagina desde otra maquina, no puedo ver los iconos del navbar y del login

**Este es el codigo de la plantilla**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Instituto Tecnologico de Chilpancingo</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Free Bootstrap Theme by BootstrapMade.com">
  <meta name="keywords" content="free website templates, free bootstrap themes, free template, free bootstrap, free website template">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Candal|Alegreya+Sans">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/imagehover.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <!-- =======================================================
    Theme Name: Mentor
    Theme URL: https://bootstrapmade.com/mentor-free-education-bootstrap-theme/
    Author: BootstrapMade.com
    Author URL: https://bootstrapmade.com
  ======================================================= -->
</head>

<body>
  <!--Navigation bar-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">It<span>Ch</span></a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#feature">Filosofia</a></li>
          <li><a href="#organisations"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Comentarios</a></li>
          <li><a href="#courses"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-education"></span> Conferencias</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#pricing"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Cupos</a></li>
          <li class="btn-trial"><a href="#" data-target="#login" data-toggle="modal">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
             Acceder
          </a></li>          
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!--/ Navigation bar-->
  <!--Modal box-->
  <div class="modal fade" id="login" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">

      <!-- Modal content no 1-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title text-center form-title">Login</h4>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body padtrbl">

          <div class="login-box-body">
            <p class="login-box-msg">Accede para iniciar tu session</p>
            <div class="form-group">
              <form name="" id="loginForm" action="checklogin.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                  <!----- username -------------->
                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="username" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="username" />
                  <span style="display:none;font-weight:bold; position:absolute;color: red;position: absolute;padding:4px;font-size: 11px;background-color:rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.26);z-index: 17;  right: 27px; top: 5px;" id="span_loginid"></span>
                  <!---Alredy exists  ! -->
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                  <!----- password -------------->
                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="password" type="password" autocomplete="off" name="password" />
                  <span style="display:none;font-weight:bold; position:absolute;color: grey;position: absolute;padding:4px;font-size: 11px;background-color:rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.26);z-index: 17;  right: 27px; top: 5px;" id="span_password"></span>
                  <!---Alredy exists  ! -->
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="checkbox icheck">
                      <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="loginrem" > Remember Me
                              </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-green btn-block btn-flat" onclick="userlogin()">Ingresar</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/ Modal box-->
  <!--Banner-->
  <div class="banner">
    <div class="bg-color">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="banner-text text-center">
            <div class="text-border">
              <h2 class="text-dec">Itchilpancingo</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="intro-para text-center quote">
              <p class="big-text">Crear tecnologia es forjar libertad.</p>
              <p class="small-text">Av. José Francisco Ruiz Massieu No. 5, Colonia Villa Moderna, 39090 Chilpancingo de los Bravo, Gro.<br>Teléfono: 01 747 472 7152<br>Fundación: 12 de febrero de 1985</p>
              <a href="#footer" class="btn get-quote">GET A QUOTE</a>
            </div>
            <a href="#feature" class="mouse-hover">
              <div class="mouse"></div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/ Banner-->
  <!--Feature-->
  <section id="feature" class="section-padding">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="header-section text-center">
          <h2>Features</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem nesciunt vitae,<br> maiores, magni dolorum aliquam.</p>
          <hr class="bottom-line">
        </div>
        <div class="feature-info">
          <div class="fea">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="heading pull-right">
                <h4>Mision</h4>
                <p>“Preservar, innovar, transcender y aplicar el conocimiento científico-tecnológico en la formación de profesionistas, con responsabilidad social y capacidad de investigar, que desarrollen y apliquen propuestas de solución a la problemática de la sociedad.”</p>
              </div>
              <div class="fea-img pull-left">
                <i class="fa fa-flag"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="fea">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="heading pull-right">
                <h4>Vision</h4>
                <p>“Ser una institución pública de educación superior de calidad, con compromiso social, en la que preserve, innove y transcienda el conocimiento científico-tecnológico para su aplicación en el estudio y solución de los problemas de la sociedad.”</p>
              </div>
              <div class="fea-img pull-left">
                <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="fea">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="heading pull-right">
                <h4>Valores Institucionales</h4>
                <p>-Compromiso social<br>Atender a la satisfacción de las necesidades de la sociedad<br>-Responsabilidad ambiental<br>Compromiso con el mejoramiento de las condiciones del medio ambiente.<br>-Preservación cultural<br>Conservación de los rangos de origen y evolución de la sociedad mexicana y los principios que fundamentan su carácter de nación.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="fea-img pull-left">
                <i class="fa fa-university"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--/ feature-->
  <!--Organisations-->
  <section id="organisations" class="section-padding">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <div class="orga-stru">
              <h3>65%</h3>
              <p>Say NO!!</p>
              <i class="fa fa-male"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <div class="orga-stru">
              <h3>20%</h3>
              <p>Says Yes!!</p>
              <i class="fa fa-male"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <div class="orga-stru">
              <h3>15%</h3>
              <p>Can't Say!!</p>
              <i class="fa fa-male"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="detail-info">
            <hgroup>
              <h3 class="det-txt"> Is inclusive quality education affordable?</h3>
              <h4 class="sm-txt">(Revised and Updated for 2016)</h4>
            </hgroup>
            <p class="det-p">Donec et lectus bibendum dolor dictum auctor in ac erat. Vestibulum egestas sollicitudin metus non urna in eros tincidunt convallis id id nisi in interdum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--/ Organisations-->
  <!--Cta-->
  <section id="cta-2">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <h2 class="text-center">Subscribe Now</h2>
          <p class="cta-2-txt">Sign up for our free weekly software design courses, we’ll send them right to your inbox.</p>
          <div class="cta-2-form text-center">
            <form action="#" method="post" id="workshop-newsletter-form">
              <input name="" placeholder="Enter Your Email Address" type="email">
              <input class="cta-2-form-submit-btn" value="Subscribe" type="submit">
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--/ Cta-->
  <!--work-shop-->
  <section id="work-shop" class="section-padding">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="header-section text-center">
          <h2>Upcoming Workshop</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem nesciunt vitae,<br> maiores, magni dolorum aliquam.</p>
          <hr class="bottom-line">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
          <div class="service-box text-center">
            <div class="icon-box">
              <i class="fa fa-html5 color-green"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-text">
              <h4 class="ser-text">Mentor HTML5 Workshop</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
          <div class="service-box text-center">
            <div class="icon-box">
              <i class="fa fa-css3 color-green"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-text">
              <h4 class="ser-text">Mentor CSS3 Workshop</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
          <div class="service-box text-center">
            <div class="icon-box">
              <i class="fa fa-joomla color-green"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="icon-text">
              <h4 class="ser-text">Mentor Joomla Workshop</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--/ work-shop-->
  <!--Faculity member-->
  <section id="faculity-member" class="section-padding">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="header-section text-center">
          <h2>Conoce a los ponentes</h2>
          <p>Cada uno estos profesionales proceden de empresas<br> del sector educativo y privado.</p>
          <hr class="bottom-line">
        </div>
        <?php include 'mostrar_ponentes.php'; ?>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--/ Faculity member-->
  <!--Testimonial-->
  <section id="testimonial" class="section-padding">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="header-section text-center">
          <h2 class="white">See What Our Customer Are Saying?</h2>
          <p class="white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem nesciunt vitae,<br> maiores, magni dolorum aliquam.</p>
          <hr class="bottom-line bg-white">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="text-comment">
            <p class="text-par">"Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, nec sagittis sem"</p>
            <p class="text-name">Abraham Doe - Creative Dırector</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="text-comment">
            <p class="text-par">"Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, nec sagittis sem"</p>
            <p class="text-name">Abraham Doe - Creative Dırector</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--/ Testimonial-->
  <!--Courses-->
  <section id="courses" class="section-padding">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="header-section text-center">
          <h2>Conferencias</h2>
          <p>La disponibilidad depende de la cantidad de lugares libre para los asistentes,<br> el maximo numero de asistentes es de 50.</p>
          <hr class="bottom-line">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <?php include 'mostrar_conferencias.php'; ?>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--/ Courses-->
  <!--Pricing-->
  <section id="pricing" class="section-padding">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="header-section text-center">
          <h2>Cupo</h2>
          <p>Lugares disponibles para cada una de las conferencias.</p>
          <hr class="bottom-line">
        </div>
        <?php include 'mostrar_cupo.php'; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--/ Pricing-->
  <!--Contact-->
  <section id="contact" class="section-padding">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="header-section text-center">
          <h2>Contact Us</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem nesciunt vitae,<br> maiores, magni dolorum aliquam.</p>
          <hr class="bottom-line">
        </div>
        <div id="sendmessage">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
        <div id="errormessage"></div>
        <form action="" method="post" role="form" class="contactForm">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 left">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control form" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
              <div class="validation"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
              <div class="validation"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
              <div class="validation"></div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 right">
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
              <div class="validation"></div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <!-- Button -->
            <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="form contact-form-button light-form-button oswald light">SEND EMAIL</button>
          </div>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--/ Contact-->
  <!--Footer-->
  <footer id="footer" class="footer">
    <div class="container text-center">

      <h3>Start Your Free Trial Now!</h3>

      <form class="mc-trial row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-4">
          <div class=" controls">
            <input name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End email input -->
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-4">
          <div class=" controls">
            <input name="EMAIL" placeholder="Enter Your email" class="form-control" type="email">
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End email input -->
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
          <p>
            <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-submit">
            Submit <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
          </p>
        </div>
      </form>
      <!-- End newsletter-form -->
      <ul class="social-links">
        <li><a href="#link"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#link"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#link"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-fw"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#link"><i class="fa fa-dribbble fa-fw"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#link"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-fw"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
      ©2018 ITCH. All rights reserved
      <div class="credits">
        <!--
          All the links in the footer should remain intact.
          You can delete the links only if you purchased the pro version.
          Licensing information: https://bootstrapmade.com/license/
          Purchase the pro version with working PHP/AJAX contact form: https://bootstrapmade.com/buy/?theme=Mentor
        -->        
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!--/ Footer-->

  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
  <script src="contactform/contactform.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Y esté es link del servidor que estoy usando para probar la pagina

http://conferenciastec.sytes.net/Mentor

Comment: error 404 verifica que la ruta que pusiste es la correcta, pues te esta indicando que no encuentra el archivo donde tu lo estas indicando

Comment: ya coloque bien la ruta ¿puedes probar acceder a ella?

Comment: nop mismo error

Comment: pero tres amigos míos, pueden acceder desde sus casas, incluso desde sus teléfonos

Comment: con que navegador no se ven los glyphs?

Comment: con google chrome

Comment: que iconos? si llego a ver tus iconos del navbar y el login. estoy desde google chrome

Comment: es que reemplace esta linea:
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
por esta otra:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: usa el link directo, pero como le hago para usar los archivos que venían cuando baje la plantilla